# swift URLRequest doesn't send parameters

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest

In the code below

```
    let bodyData = "?sub=\(id)&name=User&email=test@test.com"
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get");
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url as! URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main)
    {
        (response, data, error) in
        if let HTTPResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

            if statusCode == 200 {
                // Yes, Do something. 
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] {
                    let args = dictionary["args"]
                    NSLog("args:\(args)")
                    for (key, value) in dictionary{
                        NSLog("key:\(key) value:\(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

id is a string passed in to the function.

It has valid data returned, but the test site/url also returns in json format any parameters you send it.  But this snippet of code seems to not be sending the query parameters defined in bodyData and I can't figure out why.

Comment: JSON top level object must be an Array or Dictionary and u need to use JSONSerialization to get the JSON data from it. you should use URL instead of NSURL and URLRequest instead of NSURLReques. if you need mutable request declare URLRequest as variable.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  Turns out that GET methods do not append the query parameters to the URL.  Therefore the parameters need to be part of the URL when creating the request.

Comment: Yes I didn't notice you were using get instead of post. You can use URLComponents

Answer (score 1):

If a GET request is used the parameters are appended to the URL and an explicit `URLRequest` is not needed at all.

This code is native Swift 3 and uses contemporary API:

```
let id = 12

let bodyData = "?sub=\(id)&name=User&email=test@test.com"
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get" + bodyData)!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

    if error != nil  {
        print(error!)
        return
    }

    do {
       if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any],
          let args = json["args"] as? [String:Any] {
            print("args:\(args)")
            for (key, value) in args{
                print("key:\(key) value:\(value)")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Appending the query parameters to the URL works, but the above code did not compile for me.  dataTask caused the error.

Comment: I tested exactly this code successfully in a Swift 3 Playground. Use the native Swift structs without `NS`